# Paste a Table from Microsoft Excel After Heading 1 in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a problem where i'm when i copy paste a table from Microsoft Excel to Microsoft Word, it erases the whole document with the table, What i want is to paste the table under heading 1 ( eg. 1. Introduction, 2. Submission, 3. Sources, 4. Table) under heading 4. Table. And keep the other info erased (1,2 & 3) These are the code to paste the table from Excel.

```
 
    Sub ActivateWord()
    Worksheets("France").Range("France_Table").Copy
    'Declare Object variables for the Word application and document.
    Dim WdApp As Object, wddoc As Object
    'Declare a String variable for the example document’s
    'name and folder path.
    Dim strDocName As String
    'On Error statement if Word is not already open.
    On Error Resume Next
    'Activate Word if it is already open.
    Set WdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Err.Clear
    'Create a Word application if Word is not already open.
    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    'Make sure the Word application is visible.
    If sPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Microsoft Word Macro-Enabled Document"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    WdApp.Visible = True
    'Define the strDocName String variable.
    strDocName = sPath
    'Check the directory for the presence of the document
    'name in the folder path.
    'If it is not recognized, inform the user of that
    'fact and exit the macro.
    If Dir(strDocName) = "" Then
        MsgBox "The file " & strDocName & vbCrLf & _
        "was not found in the folder path" & vbCrLf & _
        "sPath", _
        vbExclamation, _
        "Sorry, that document name does not exist."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Activate the Word application.
    WdApp.Activate
    'Set the Object variable for the Word document’s full
    'name and folder path.
    Set wddoc = WdApp.Documents(strDocName)
    'If the Word document is not already open, then open it.
    If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(strDocName)
    '    The document is open, so activate it.
    wddoc.Activate
    wddoc.Range.Find.Text = "Sources"
    wddoc.Range.Find.Style = "Heading 1"
    wddoc.Range.Paste
    wddoc.Save
    WdApp.Quit
    'Release the system memory that was reserved for the two
    'Object variables.
     Set wddoc = Nothing
     Set WdApp = Nothing
     'wddoc.Close
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
      'MsgBox "Update Complete, Please Find you File at = " & vbCrLf & _
      '"Excel To Word\Excel to Word(Completed)"
       End Sub
```

```
       Set myRange = wddoc.Content
      'myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=StartWord
      myRange.Find.MatchWholeWord = True
      myRange.Find.Style = "Heading 1"
      WdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading,_
      Which:=wdGoToAbsoluteCount:=4
      Set myRange = myRange.Next
      myRange.Paste
      wddoc.Save
```

i couldn't paste the table at the heading no.4 , because there is 2 heading with the same name, is there any possible way to do that? like Goto heading 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this:**

```
wddoc.Range.Find.Text = "Sources"
wddoc.Range.Find.Style = "Heading 1"
wddoc.Range.Paste
```

**To:**
**Edited:** I had to remove as Range so that it wouldn't be cast into an Excel Range.  
**Added:** Set myRange = myRange.Next

```
Dim myRange
Set myRange = wddoc.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="Sources"
myRange.Find.Style = "Heading 1"
Set myRange = myRange.Next
myRange.Paste
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas Inzina for answering, but it doesn't solve it, the table from Excel still replaces paragraph and data in the Word document

Comment: Still, doesn't do the trick, Do i keep the wddoc.Range.Find.Style?, the Word file wasn't change at all, empty changes.

Comment: yes you are right, removing "as Range" solves the problem, but it paste right after the word "Sources", which code repalces the word "Sources" with table,can i know is there is anyway i can paste the table after the next line

Comment: is there anyway i could go to the heading 4 with goto function, am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider the following refactoring:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyExcelTableToWordDoc()
    'Declare Object variables for the Word application and document.
    Dim WdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
    'Declare a String variable for the example document’s name and folder path.
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim sPath As String '<--| do you actually need it? isn't "strDocName" the same? if no, remember to initialize it

    'Define the strDocName String variable.
    strDocName = sPath '<--| where has "sPath" been initialized?

    'Check the directory for the presence of the document name in the folder path.
    'If it is not recognized, inform the user of that fact and exit the macro.
    If Dir(strDocName) = "" Then
        MsgBox "The file " & strDocName & vbCrLf & _
        "was not found in the folder path" & vbCrLf & _
        "sPath", _
        vbExclamation, _
        "Sorry, that document name does not exist."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set WdApp = GetWord() '<--| get a Word instance (either running or a new one)
    WdApp.Visible = True '<--| make it visible

    Set wdDoc = GetWordDoc(WdApp, strDocName) '<--| get the document instance
    With wdDoc.Content
        With .Find  '<--| set the Find object and execute it on the entire document content
            .ClearFormatting
            .Style = "Heading 1"
            .Execute FindText:="Sources", Format:=True, Forward:=True
        End With
        If .Find.found Then '<--| if Find is successful...
            .Collapse Direction:=1 '<--| ...collapse the selection to the beginning of the found range (1=wdCollapseStart)...
            .Move Unit:=4, Count:=1 '<--| ...move to the beginning of the next paragraph (4=wdParagraph)...
            Worksheets("France").Range("France_Table").Copy '<--| ...copy the table...
            .Paste '<--| ... paste into word document...
            Application.CutCopyMode = False '<--| ... clear excel clipboard...
            wdDoc.Save '<--| ... and finally save word document, since you actually changed it!
        End If
    End With

    WdApp.Quit 'close Word
    'Release the system memory that was reserved for the two Object variables.
     Set wdDoc = Nothing
     Set WdApp = Nothing
     'MsgBox "Update Complete, Please Find you File at = " & vbCrLf & _
     '"Excel To Word\Excel to Word(Completed)"
End Sub

Function GetWord() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    'Activate Word if it is already open.
    Set GetWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If GetWord Is Nothing Then
        'Create a Word application if Word is not already open.
        Set GetWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
    End If
End Function

Function GetWordDoc(WdApp As Object, strDocName As String) As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWordDoc = WdApp.Documents(strDocName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'If the Word document is not already open, then open it.
    If GetWordDoc Is Nothing Then Set GetWordDoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(strDocName)
End Function
```

what above to:

- do "things" only if and when needed

  for instance

  - all the Word stuff (application and document setting) is done only after passing the `If Dir(strDocName) = "" Then` check
  - excel table copying is done only if the word `Find()` object has been successfully executed
  - word document is saved only if excel table has been actually pasted
  - clipboard clearing is made only if the corresponding `Copy()` has been previously issued
- demand Word application and document settings to specific functions so as not to clutter main sub code
- limit `On Error Resume Next` statements only when needed and inside functions so as not to hide any other possible error (and which you want to know about) outside them

Comment: thank you, i will try out the to do things. Thanks again